# feeds not update exist node and only add them

Tags: 7, feeds, nodes

I am using feeds module in order to import node from csv file,
The mapping equation is 
[image]

and the updating criteria set to 
[image]

and my csv file contain this

```
guid,field_type,field_model,field_cost,
1,type1,model1,cost300,
2,type1,model2,cost300,
3,type1,model3,cost300,
4,type1,model4,cost400,
5,type1,model5,cost5,
6,type6,model6,cost6,
7,type7,model7,cost7,
8,type8,model8,cost8,
9,type9,model9,cost9,
10,type10,model10,cost10,
```

**my problem is every time i import csv file the recorded added to my node (not update or replace), where is the problem?**

Comment: Have you tried setting the guid as unique?

Comment: @hampusn , thank you very much I found my mistake :)

Comment: zhilevan, @hampusn it seems you know the answer, so maybe one of you could post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here `NOT UNIQUE field set`.after set a field as a unique field every time the nodes will update(replaced).
To  set a field as unique click a button below not set as unique , check unique checkbox and update then it will set as unique.